# Google api -- prevent markers from changing size when zooming

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm using google api and I'm having some trouble with markers.
Whenever I zoom in, or zoom out, the map markers keep changing their size; how can I just fix the size?

I don't mean fix the size to the center, I want to still make the markers disappear when you move far away enough, I just want to prevent the constant resize from occurring.

Having a static image is not an option because I want the user to be able to zoom in and move around the map.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply catch the zoom event

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
   zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
   if (zoomLevel >= whenYouWantTheMarkerToDisapear) {
       //Run thought your marker array and call .setSize()
    }
});
```

Sth like this should do what you want. 
If you want something more specific, add your code and we will see